# How to trouble shoot 9-patch image problem in android

Tags: android

I have an ImageView in my layout xml file. I set the width to wrap_content and height to fill_parent.  In hierarchy viewer, the width is 2 px and height is 120 px. But when I see it on device, my 9-patch image for the image view does not stretch to 120 px. Can you please tell me how can I trouble shoot this 9 patch image does not stretch error?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post your xml layout?

Comment: Are you setting ImageView height, width with default values; if thats the case you woulds see this issue or else if you placing your ImageView inside some other view which is static please try the Layout XML setting every component to fill_parent if the Problem persists please post you XML Layout.

Answer (score 7):

You have to set android:scaleType in order for the ImageView to resize the 9-patch.  Normally you will want to set it to fitXY.